# failed using cuda-gdb walking-through example

Tags: cuda-gdb

I am trying the walking-through example in CUDA-GDB manual, and follow exactly the same compilation command. I am using CUDA-4 on Fermi M2090, and CUDA-GDB failed with the following message when I type "run" under GDB environment:

```
/home/buildmeister/build/rel/gpgpu/toolkit/r4.1/debugger/cuda-gdb/7.2/gdb/cuda-tdep.c:1203: internal-error: cuda_get_bfd_abi_version: Assertion `CUDA_ELFOSABIV_16BIT <= abiv && abiv <= CUDA_ELFOSABIV_LATEST' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced same problem. (Kepler architecture, ubuntu 13.04) I have done some research and found out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373255/cuda-driver-initialization-failed).

The problem occurs because of your driver version is higher than your toolkit version. Your toolkit isn't able to recognize your driver. I have solved this problem by installing Cuda-Toolkit-5.5 (Release Candidate) and display driver from the same self extracting package.

I have done this because it is almost impossible to install cuda toolkit 5.0 on a kernel 3.8+.

You can find the instructions here on [my blog page](http://zgrw.org/blog.php?id=12).